# How to inject custom CSS in Modern Site Pages using SPFx Extensions

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, spfx-extensions

I would like to inject Custom css in modern site pages. 
Here i need to change all the fonts on the modern site and i would like to achieve this via App Customizer with SPFx Extensions.
Any tips Or help ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the demo shared by [hugoabernier](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss).

```
public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);

    const cssUrl: string = this.properties.cssurl;
    if (cssUrl) {
        // inject the style sheet
        const head: any = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
        let customStyle: HTMLLinkElement = document.createElement("link");
        customStyle.href = cssUrl;
        customStyle.rel = "stylesheet";
        customStyle.type = "text/css";
        head.insertAdjacentElement("beforeEnd", customStyle);
    }

    return Promise.resolve();
  }
```